# CSS hide an image when scroll

Tags: css

I am trying to add an animation that moves an image and when the user scrolls down the content will hide this image.

If I have an image without any animation like this one, it would work and the content will hide the image when the user scrolls down.

```
  header {
    height: calc(100vh - 22px);
    background-size: cover;
    background: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/abdel-rahman-ali/image/upload/v1535988534/header.jpg") fixed bottom;
    padding: 20px 70px;
}
```

However, once I try to add the keyframes to apply the animation and scroll down the content doesn't hide the image.

```
 @keyframes background {
    0% {
        background: url(https://res.cloudinary.com/abdel-rahman-ali/image/upload/v1535988534/header.jpg) no-repeat 50% 30%;
        background-size: 100%;
        transition: background 0.5s ;
   }
    100% {
        background: url(https://res.cloudinary.com/abdel-rahman-ali/image/upload/v1535988534/header.jpg) no-repeat 50% 60%;
        background-size: 100%;
        transition: background 0.5s ;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have it trigger when you scroll, you would need to use JavaScript:

When the document is scrolled, it will fire the event listener. Then check whether the scroll position has reached 350px. If it is greater than 350px, it will set opacity of the header to 0. If the scroll position is less than or equal to 350px, then it will compute the opacity value.

Set the header with an id of header:

```
<header id="header">
</header>
```

JS:

```
let header = document.getElementById('header');

document.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    // Get scroll position
    let scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;

    // Calculate whether the scroll it 350px or not then set the opacity to face the header out
    if (scrollPosition <= 350) {
        header.style.opacity = 1 - scrollPosition / 350;
    } else {
        header.style.opacity = 0;
    }

});
```

---

(In reference to below comment)

**How to have have the background image fixed**

To have the image stay while the content slides over will be the `background-attachment` property in css.

```
#header {
   width: 100%;
   max-height: 100vh;
   background-image: url(); /* Set the background image */
   background-attachment: fixed; /* This makes the image not scroll when the user scrolls */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, any idea about how can I apply the animation and make the content below the image covers it while scrolling down, in this video it works with a normal image. However, I want it to work with the effect [Normal Image Effect](https://files.fm/f/z8ydzrthr)

Comment: You would use ´background-attachment´ and set it to ´fixed´. I edited my answer and added an example of the attribute.